# Kubernetes load balancing between 2 services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed my microservices as 2 separate service - ServiceA & ServiceB, with a pod within each service. I want a load balancer that can route the traffic to either ServiceA or ServiceB.
Its kind of an alternate backend, we have similar options in Openshift using routes but can we do it in AWS ingress controller and specify alternate backend services.

In openshift we can use the below route configuration

```
spec:
  alternateBackends:
    - kind: Service
      name: ServiceB
      weight: 25
  host: lb.apps.xyz.com
  port:
    targetPort: https
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ServiceA
    weight: 75
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

Comment: what exactly is your question ? As per my understanding you already know the answer :)

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same using AWS ALB ingress controller, do we have the option to set alternateBackends

Comment: https://akomljen.com/aws-alb-ingress-controller-for-kubernetes/

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't have the same concept I am looking for. I can create a single alb and point it to multiple services based on context path, but my ask is context path is same and I want to load balance/failover between 2 services and provide necessary weights